# Do not lose privileges once gained

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties, privileges

According to the answers here at meta, you can lose privileges when you e.g. spend your reputation on bounties. What is the rationale behind that?

By my opinion, it would be more natural if the privileges are persistent once gained. The user is given privileges once he was "tested" by the community. He has to spend some time at the site to gain reputation and see how it works. We consider him trustworthy then.

**Once the person is trustworthy, what makes him untrustworthy when he spends his reputation on bounties? Does he become a beginner then? Will he suddenly forget everything he learned at SO?**

P.S.: I would understand it for **negative points from downvotes** (or penalties, if there are any). But when placing bounties.... or when your answers are migrated (I don't know if you lose points in this situation) I don't really see any reason to lose privileges.

Comment: Also related: [Notify user when setting a bounty will revoke a privilege](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11930/notify-user-when-setting-a-bounty-will-revoke-a-privilege), [Does loss of reputation cause loss of privileges?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76374/does-loss-of-reputation-cause-loss-of-privileges)

Comment: @Cody Gray, Bobby, Marc Gravell: I'm quite surprised you closed it - None of the "duplicates" really discuss the arguments I've just put. Please reopen the question to let the discussion go.

Comment: No, the "possible duplicate" question linked at the top of the question addresses your concerns pretty explicitly... The question says: "Should this [be] changed? Or is this ideal?" And the answers explain why people think it should not be changed. Feel free to post an answer of your own there, agreeing that it *should* be changed.

Comment: (Unrelated: Note that only the first person is notified of an @ comment. That means Bobby and Marc didn't see your comment. You can ping individual close-voters, but you can't do it with a single comment.)