# All of today's reputation lost and demoted from editor

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

Today I got 25 reputation but I see it is reduced to 1976 as of yesterday. I was very eager to get to the 2000 milestone and I received it.

But after a while I could see I lost 25 reputation that I gained today. 
My answers are still there. Questions and answers are not removed and they are upvoted and answered also. Here is this link for the same.

[Each call to StringBuffer#toString and StrinBuilder#toString returns new instance or instance from string pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720883/each-call-to-stringbuffertostring-and-strinbuildertostring-returns-new-instanc/17720940#17720940)

What is the cause of this? I am not able to understand.

Comment: Did you enable "show removed posts" at the bottom of the reputation tab page?

Comment: Curious; why do we demote people from privileges?  Seems to me once you earn a privilege it's silly to remove it, unless moderation action is necessary for significant malfeasance.  Given `2000` is an arbitrary point, why not just leave him with Editor privilege?

Comment: @Joe: Even if the reputation was gained through fraud?

Comment: just curious, how is reputation earned through fraud?

Comment: @AlEverett, unless it was a significant fraud such that a moderator took specific punitive action, sure.  What's the real difference between a 1975 user and a 2000 user?  Doesn't seem like it's enough to matter, and removing privilege for either something minor (like a relatively unoffensive but off-topic post being deleted) or even a single downvote seems petty.

Comment: @Joe: Discussed quite a bit [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4780/is-losing-privileges-after-placing-bounty-ok) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156587/privilege-to-review-suggested-edits-revoked-when-i-placed-a-bounty) (although, admittedly, this in the context of losing privileges as a result of posting a bounty).

Comment: Also [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76374/does-loss-of-reputation-cause-loss-of-privileges).

Comment: @Prasad: By getting your friends (real or imaginary) to create accounts and vote up your stuff, regardless of merit.

Comment: @PrasadKharkar oooh you'll find that you are back over 2000 ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you view your removed posts history, you'll see you lost 25 reputation today from this post being deleted:

[String variable still returns an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506923/string-variable-still-returns-an-error/17506950#17506950)

You had one up-vote and an Accept on it, so that explains the 25.

For the record, the question was deleted about 15 minutes ago by [Community ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)  - <sub>So, don't blame it on me ;)</sub>

Comment: Its not about blaming at all sir :) . I just wanted to know what happened. I didn't notice the question was removed.

Comment: @PrasadKharkar I was only joking about the blaming part. hehe I do delete a *lot* of content, and I get 'mentioned' here a bit for doing it. I agree that the answer was not remotely 'terrible'!

Comment: It would appear the entire question was auto-deleted because the user was destroyed... Take anyone out with an axe recently? Perhaps they deleted their own account?

Comment: Can you provide a link to these kinds of common questions here on meta SO? I don't know how exactly community works :(

Comment: @animuson D'oh! Another option that could have been my fault! hehe... I don't think I'd ever do a 'Destroy' on a user with a question with an accepted answer that wasn't from a sock or the like, though.

Comment: @Prasad: For your reading pleasure: [meta-tag:faq]

Comment: Maybe a rogue Dalek came through?

Comment: @Joe Hmm... do you think it would be appropriate to call myself *both* the Evil Unicorn Overlord, *and* something Dalek-related? I do like *exterminating* content. And users...

Comment: @AndrewBarber Hmmmmmm blame it on Community, you better hope Community is never given consciousness ;)

Comment: @Yve That is among my most earnest prayers each and every morning. Did you know mods can't even suspend it???!?!?! ;)