# Bounty, someone elses question and can't comment?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, comments, bounties

Ok so I recently posted a bounty on this [question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/24786/why-deoxyribose-for-dna-and-ribose-for-rna/45690#45690), which is not my own. This has taken me from 90 reps to 40 reps. This leaves me in a situation where I can't comment on the question or answers, which subsequently means I can't e.g. ask for more information, that I think is necessary to (properly) award the bounty.

I know I should have thought about this before placing it, but is there any way around this situation?

**Edit**

The linked [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192403/comment-on-posts-that-you-have-an-open-bounty-on-despite-reputation) although on the same lines as this one, was posted 2 years ago, with most comments saying it is a very rare event. The answers given thus relate to the situation 2 years ago and not now. Has the situation changed at all since then, or not?

Comment: Related: [Comment on posts that you have an open bounty on, despite reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192403/255554)

Comment: Voting up. If you put a bounty on someone else's question, you're already committed to the question. The reasons for the 50 point threshold no longer apply.

Comment: Regarding your edit: no, nothing has changed.