# Can't add comment in the question I posted a bounty for

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties

Posting a bounty for [How to navigate a lot of tabs in Google Chrome on iOS (iPad)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/248183/how-to-navigate-a-lot-of-tabs-in-google-chrome-on-ios-ipad) was my first activity on the StackExchange site 'Ask Different', and apparently I didn't get any reputation bonus for joining that site (as usually seems to happen) because my reputation there shows as 1. As a result, I can't comment to answers (or the question itself) on the question I posted the bounty for.

Is it a bug that I didn't get the reputation bonus when I joined a site in this way? Because there's what appears to be a +100 message stuck in my StacExchange inbox--it has a completely blank subject--and nothing happens when I click on it.

Regardless of that, if you think about it logically, shouldn't sponsoring bounty on an affiliated site trigger a special case that ensures you can at least comment in the thread?

---

[edit:] As I explain in an answer below, I mistakenly thought that a person's reputation was fluid across all StackExchange network sites. In fact, it's tabulated separately, and reputation from one site cannot be used at another.]

Answer (score 0):

Now I see, the bounty was deducted from my reputation on that site, not from my reputation points from the other network sites.

Still doesn't explain the blank message in my inbox though:

[image]

Comment: I don't see a blank message... ? Can you draw on your image to highlight where you're talking about?

Comment: If, by chance, you're talking about the line right under "yesterday"... that's not blank. It's the per-site running total for the day. Add together everything between "yesterday" and "last 30 days" and you get what's in that first bar. The bounty cancelled out your association bonus, so there's no icon for Ask Different.

Comment: Also, bounties have never (and likely will never) come from wider network rep. They must come from that site's rep pool. There have been requests for "fund bounties from other sites' rep" in the past and they were declined.

Comment: @Catija Yes, that was the blank area I was talking about. Thanks for your excellent and comprehensive replies.

Comment: @Catija did those "fund bounties from other sites' rep" proposals include the possibility of *fractional* transfer of same? While one can agree that expertise in one specific area may not fully transfer, there's a certain degree to which a person's engagement with the universe, in general, might be probative across disparate topic areas.