# What will happen after the great reputation re-calc?

Tags: discussion, reputation, reputation-recalc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lose Rep Accomplishments…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4780/lose-rep-accomplishments)

I have just gotten close-voting privileges on SO.  Jeff in the past has [talked about a rep-recalc coming in the future](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/should-the-weight-of-downvotes-be-increased) with downvotes being increased to -5 points; if this is done, I may well go below 3000 (I still don't understand some of my downvotes...).  Will I lose my close-vote privileges?

Comment: The great recalc is a myth, like Atlantis and fat-free food that tastes good.

Comment: That said, dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4780/lose-rep-accomplishments

Comment: I didn't think that podcast aired on April 1st?

Comment: Fire and brimstone coming down from the skies! Rivers and seas boiling! Forty years of darkness! Earthquakes, volcanoes... The dead rising from the grave! Human sacrifice, dogs and cats living together... mass hysteria!

Comment: Oh, it's not a myth. The Mayans predicted it... so did Nostradamus. It's a widely believed fact.

Comment: You're allowed to say things you don't mean (or say things that you mean but then choose to not follow through on) on days other than April 1.

Comment: For those wondering about the rep-recalc (since I can't edit the question) he's referring to the upcoming change in downvote cost/consequence discussed here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/should-the-weight-of-downvotes-be-increased There is no published timeframe for this to happen, though, but it is planned.

Comment: @Adam - of course there is; 6-8 weeks!

Comment: LOL - of course!  I forgot.  There's a website out there for that...

Answer (score 3):

**What will happen after the great reputation re-calc?**

Most people will lose some reputation.  Those that have made very subjective/controversial posts with a lot of up and down votes will lose more than those that made objective/noncontroversial posts.

**Will I lose my close-vote privileges?**

If you drop below 3,000 rep, then yes.  You can query the database dump to approximate how much you might lose.  They just handed out the latest dump from October.

[Sam Saffron's post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/should-the-weight-of-downvotes-be-increased/7332#7332) has a lot more information on the users that stand to lose the most, and includes the query which you can modify to give you an idea as to how much you would be affected.  As pointed out by Joel in the comments, the full rep query is rather complex and difficult to duplicate in the datadump.  But it should give you an idea.

However, as Sam's post pointed out, few people will lose more than 200 rep, and 200 rep can be gained in a day.  So the rep calculation will likely set most people back by perhaps a day.  You can prepare for it by working ahead, if it concerns you.

Comment: The query required to view your actual rep in the data dump is not trivial- some subtlies around when to exclude and when not to exclude votes.

Comment: Also: the data dump lacks information about your downvotes you place.

Comment: Ah, yes.  People were worried about their anonymous voting becoming public.  Well, one can only approximate the change with a query to the public sources, but it's better than nothing if one really, really, really has to know, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

> Will I lose my close-vote privileges?

If you do, so what? You'll get them back soon enough.