# If your reputation goes down from awarding a bounty, or from being voted down by other users, do you lose abilities?

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lose Rep Accomplishments…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4780/lose-rep-accomplishments)

For example, at 1000 reputation, you gain the ability to see total up and down vote counts. If you were to lose reputation from either awarding a bounty, or other users voting down your posts, would you lose the ability to see total up and down vote counts, or would it be retained after attaining it the first time? Is there a differentiation between losing reputation to bounty and being down-voted or does the system treat them the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you were to lose reputation from either awarding a bounty, or other users voting down your posts, would you lose the ability to see total up and down vote counts, or would it be retained after attaining it the first time?

You would loose the ability.

> Is there a differentiation between losing reputation to bounty and being down-voted or does the system treat them the same?

While they're stored in a way that we can tell what they are (bounties vs downvotes), the actual system doesn't care. It is all just a number.

Bottom Line: The system looks at your current reputation, and that is it.