# Reputations & privileges vs. bounties

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties, privileges

I'd ask following question: let say I have achieved certain amount of reputation & privileges (e.g. 8000 - so I would have full access to moderator tools). Next day I have decided to reward someone with 100 bounty points. That would mean that 100 points will be deducted from my reputation. Does it mean that I won't have full access to moderator tools?

If so: do you think that it's a bit unfair and it might lead that people won't be interested to reward others with bounties?

Comment: Possible dup http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67847/can-you-lose-an-ability-if-your-reputation-falls-below-a-threshold

Comment: Nope a bit different. I am asking about "do you think that it's a bit unfair and it might lead that people won't be interested to reward others with bounties?"

Comment: Where did 8000 come from? I think you meant 10000

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, your conclusion is correct. Your privileges track your current reputation score.
2. It doesn't strike me as unfair (whatever that means). Bounties are for users who would really, really like to see an answer to their question. For most, I don't imagine losing access to certain privileges (that they'll likely regain soon) is much of a disincentive.