# Can you lose privileges?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you lose an ability if your reputation falls below a threshold?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67847/can-you-lose-an-ability-if-your-reputation-falls-below-a-threshold)

This is purely from an interest viewpoint because I haven't found the question asked elsewhere. Say I had 1100 reputation and then offered a bounty of 200 on a particular question (thus losing the 200 reputation) will I lose the privileges gained when I hit 1000 reputation until I make up the reputation again, or do they stay regardless?

I'm thinking if you lose reputation from downvotes or inappropriate posts it makes sense to lose the privileges, but if it's for something like offering a bounty then it would make sense if they stayed (after all, it's nothing you've done wrong.) Is this how it works and if not why is it done differently?

Comment: Short and to the point, but [Can you lose an ability if your reputation falls below a threshold?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67847/can-you-lose-an-ability-if-your-reputation-falls-below-a-threshold) covers everything. No matter the method, rep change may cause loss of privileges.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

All privileges are based on the rep you have *now*, so any changes, bounty or otherwise will indeed cause a change in [privileges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges) if you cross some threshold, in either direction.