# Can't comment on Super User on a question I've set a bounty on

Tags: support, comments, superuser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

I can't comment on any post on Super User. I tried Firefox, Chrome and Safari on my mac. I can't find the comment link at all. I even create a new account on Super User, but the new user still can't find comment link.

I realize I do not have enough reputation to post a comment on Super User after setting a bounty. But it's not reasonable not to be able to comment on a question I've set a bounty on.

Comment: You put a bounty before posting this? You should have said so when posting.

Comment: @kan - Where exactly on the post were you trying to comment?  You can only comment on the actual question or on an answer by you.  You still won't be able to comment on someone else's answer if the post doesn't belong to you...

Comment: @Lix, [this one](http://superuser.com/questions/331679/homebrew-build-with-different-arch)

Comment: Related - [Is losing privileges after placing bounty OK?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4780/is-losing-privileges-after-placing-bounty-ok)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply don't have the [required 50 reputation points](https://superuser.com/privileges/comment) to comment on Super User.

You can however still comment on your own questions or answers.

---

A question that you offered a bounty on is still not considered **your** post.

You placed a bounty on that post but it still doesn't belong to you; the comment limitation is still enforced.

---

#### Final thoughts

There is something slightly odd with loosing privileges from offering a bounty, but essentially it is not because of the bounty; it is because of the reputation drop.  A 10.0K user offering a 50 rep bounty won't have access to the [mod tools](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools), but the reputation decrease has nothing to do with his ability to contribute to the community.

There's a hole in the logic there, and I'm pretty sure it's there to not unnecessarily complicate things. I'm drifting dangerously towards a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) in an answer to a [support](/questions/tagged/support) question so I'll leave it at that!

> `Privileges = Reputation + Offered_Bounties`

Comment: I think it doesn't make sense. I can't make the answer better understanding via commenting/discussing it with contributors.

Comment: A bounty does not make it your question. You only "pay" for the question to be advertised more. Anything you want to get out of your bounty, you can state within the optional bounty message. Beyond that, it's simply somebody else's question. Not yours.

Comment: @kia - Just so that you know, your edit caused quite a heated debate in my home - is there supposed to be double or single spaces between sentences...  [Conclusion is that you were right :P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_spacing#Style_guides)  But it's gonna be hard for me to get used to that!!  `x_X`

Answer (score 5):

There is a [reputation minimum](https://superuser.com/privileges/comment) of 50 points before you can comment on any post.

You have only [42 points on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/users/49871/kane), so you are no longer there. You can, however, comment on your own posts. The [bonus you created yesterday](https://superuser.com/questions/331679/homebrew-build-with-different-arch) may have contributed to your confusion; the reputation drop caused you to loose the privilege.

Comment: Thanks for your information. But I even can't comment a question that is bounty by me.

Comment: @Kane: Indeed, you can't, and you won't be able to until you regain the missing 8 points, I am afraid.

Comment: @Kane: Congrats on regaining the privilege on SU. :-) Problem solved?

Comment: Someone is very very nice to give me a up vote, so I can comment others' questions now!